Is this thesis statement a hasty generalization?
I've been told that the following thesis statement would be considered to be a fallacy, specifically a hasty generalization.

The use of artificial intelligence, specifically generative AI, promotes homogeneity, bias, and even academic dishonesty, and thus it should not be used in an educational or professional environment.

However, I disagree with this claim for the following reasons:

A hasty generalization is a claim "made on the basis of insufficient evidence", and the essay that this thesis statement is located in provides plenty of evidence to support its claims.

Throughout my grade school career, I've been taught that a thesis statement should outline what you plan to talk about, but most importantly, assert your position on the topic. To my understanding, this thesis statement does just that.

This thesis statement (specifically the essay as a whole) has been peer reviewed, and no one has ever mentioned anything about the thesis.


Is this a hasty generalization? Also, if additional context is needed, here is the link to my essay in which the thesis statement is located.
P.S: I am a high school student, so I apologize if this question hasn't been asked in the appropriate tone. Additionally, I apologize if my writing as a whole isn't up to the standards of this forum. I'd just like to know if I've written a fallacy into my essay.

As it stands, your question is asking us to review and give feedback on your writing. That is off topic here. What you might do is edit your question and instead ask us how to avoid making hasty generalizations in your thesis statement. —— Also, you should ask whoever has given you that feedback (presumably your teacher) to explain their assessment, if you don't understand it. After all, the grading in school has the aim of teaching you how to write better essays, and if it is incomprehensible it fails its purpose.

This is perfectly valid as a thesis statement.
I suspect what is happening here is that the critic disagrees with your thesis. Of course your thesis is debatable and controversial, but that doesn't make it a "hasty generalization". That just means the other person disagrees.
Even if your thesis was poorly written and did not give adequate evidence to support the thesis statement, it would still be a valid thesis statement. Just one with inadequate support.
The nature of a thesis statement is that it states a conclusion. To criticize a thesis statement for stating a conclusion misses the whole point. Whether you agree with the conclusion or not, and whether you think the thesis adequately supports the conclusion or not.
It would be fair to criticize a thesis for failing to prove the thesis statement. But that would likely be a matter of opinion.

Although this isn't a common type of question asked on this site, I can give a couple of pointers.

A thesis is argued over an essay. If it seems like a hasty generalization, you either put it too early in your first body paragraph (a thesis is generally one of the last sentences, if not the very last sentence, in an essay), or you have not properly argued your thesis. If the latter is the case, just add more arguments to your essay! (If you need tips on how to do that, I can help further). Problem solved.

Consider who is telling you that is a hasty claim. If it's yourself, shake it off, because like you've said, you haven't received that critique thus far. If your critic is a teacher or mentor that is helping you write this body of work, then ask them what they think you should do to fix this (after all, they are the ones teaching you this). If it's a peer or someone with a similar background in writing as you, discuss it or consider *why *they think that.

Making generalizations is part of writing and always needs to be backed up by some sort of reasoning, especially in academic writing. If you're writing for fiction (not in this case, but still good to know), then some rules are broken/bent.


Overall, go with your gut. You'll learn best that way!
